# Скролл страницы при использовании svg-pan-zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице использую [Данную](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) библиотеку. 
SVG находится на ширину всего экрана. 
Может кто-нибудь знает, как сделать так, что когда zoom = 1, начинался скролл самой страницы. (А не пытался уменьшить масштаб)
Надеюсь, понятно объяснил

Comment: Как написано в документации, там есть метод `beforeZoom`, если он вернет `false`, то зум не будет происходить.

Comment: зум происходить не будет, но и страница скроллиться не будет